# Long-term proportion of convex and concave strategies in artificial financial markets

Tags: simulations, artificial-markets, multi-agent-simulations

In their classic paper "[Dynamic Strategies for Asset Allocation](https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande348/papers/PeroldSharpe.pdf)" Perold and Sharpe state:

> "That convex and concave strategies are mirror images of one
>   another tells us that the more demand there is for one of these
>   strategies, the more costly its implementation will become, and the
>   less healthy it may be for markets generally. If growing numbers of
>   investors switch to convex strategies, then markets will become more
>   volatile, for there will be insufficient buyers in down markets and
>   insufficient sellers in up markets at previously “fair” prices. In
>   this setting, those who follow concave strategies may be handsomely
>   rewarded. Conversely, if growing numbers of investors switch to
>   concave strategies, then the markets may become too stable. Prices may
>   be too slow to adjust to fair economic value. This is the most
>   rewarding environment for those following convex strategies.
>   Generally, whichever strategy is “most popular” will subsidize the
>   performance of the one that is “least popular.” Over time, this will
>   likely swell the ranks of investors following the latter and contain
>   the growth of those following the former, driving the market toward a
>   balance of the two."

**My question**
Although this seems intuitive enough I would like to find references which corroborate this result by means of multi-agent simulation in artificial financial markets.